# VBA to read the sheet and cell number and perform function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have three columns in excel, first one contains the name of the Sheet, seccond one with the cell number and third with a function i.e `SUM (A1:A10)`, written in the cell like `=SUM(A1:A10)`.

I want the VBA to read the name of the Sheet from the cell, go to the cell mentioned, and then perform the function.

```
      A          B            C
1  Sheet2       B3      =SUM(A1:A10)
```

So I want the `SUM(A1:A10)` to be performed on `Sheet2` Cells `B3`, there are around a 100 rows, so the code will read to `Used.Range` or `Column.End`

Comment: Which **specific** part are you stuck on? Iterating your source, locating your destination, or setting the formula? Show us your code, we're not going to write it all for you.

Comment: Do you want the **formula** placed in cell **B3** or the **result** placed in that cell ??

Comment: The result is to be placed in Sheet 2, cell B3 of the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Following should help

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strSheet As String, strCell As String, strFormula As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your data sheet

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row with data using Column A
        For i = 2 To lastRow                'loopthrough all the rows
            strSheet = .Range("A" & i)      'this is sheet name from colunm A
            strCell = .Range("B" & i)       'this is cell address from colunm B
            strFormula = .Range("C" & i)    'this is formula from colunm C

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheet).Range(strCell).Formula = strFormula
            'remove formula and keep only values
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheet).Range(strCell).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheet).Range(strCell).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am new to vba thats why struggling a little bit. It keeps giving me 'subscript out of range error.

Comment: @SM123 - That could probably be because you might not have a sheet named `Sheet1` in your workbook. So change `Sheet1` to your worksheet name.

Comment: There already is a sheet 1 in the wook, i renamed it to Sheet1 on the worksheet as well as the vba window

Comment: @SM123 - Could you debug and check which line is throwing error.

Comment: It gives the error when I get to ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheet).Range(strCell).Formula = strFormula
            'remove formula and keep only values
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheet).Range(strCell).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheet).Range(strCell).Value

Comment: @SM123 - Kindly check the values of `strSheet`, `strCell` and `strFormula`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Imeediate window doesnt show any values, just keeps giving object defined error

Comment: @SM123 - So you'll have to assign values to these variables then only your code will work.

Comment: in the step before are we not assigning values to it? I thought it will refer to the relvant sheet and cell and paste the function there.

Comment: @SM123 - As pe image in question, code will work if sheet name, cell address and formula are in cells A2, B2 and C2 respectively. Where is your data right now?

Comment: it is in A2,B2 and C2

Comment: @SM123 - While you debug the code do you see value for `ws` after `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") `

Comment: yeah it says ws = Nothing

Comment: @SM123 - `ws` is nothing means code didn't find worksheet called `Sheet1` that's what I'm saying. If you have multiple workbook open make sure you copy paste the code in module of correct workbook having sheet name `Sheet1`, there's no space in between.

Comment: I can send you a screenshot of where I am. I am writing my code in the module, with two sheets on the workbook Sheet1 and Sheet2. How can i send you a screenshot?

Comment: @SM123 - Add screen shot in the question.

Comment: Just addded it there

Comment: @SM123 - In cell A2 you have entered Sheet2 with space in between sheet and 2, remove that space.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Just curious is there a simple way to edit this code for cell C2? so instead if it shows { '=SUM(A2:A3)}. I still want this function to be performed in the relevant  cell but this way what is being performed is highlighted on sheet 1 also. Does it make sense?  i.e Cell C2 will show '=SUM(A2:A3) so C2 wont recognize this as a formula, but I want this formula Sum(A2:A3) to be performed on the relevant sheet and cell as defined.

Comment: Do you mean on entering a formula in `Cell C2` should formula be calculated in mentioned sheet?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. I am just trying to edit the code now to recognize the sheet on a different workbook, and perform the function there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read the answer and coordinate with your own circumstances.

Throw the comments.

Here you are...

```
Sub SM123()

    'Calculates used range or column end of destination Sheet that mentioned in A1 cell, So revise the range of used in C1 formula.
    Dim SH As Integer
    SH = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Formula = "=SUM(A1:A" & SH & ")"

    'Perform your thinking formula.        
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value).Range(ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value).Formula = _
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Formula

End Sub
```